# Interactive variable in Rmd

Tags: r, variables, interactive, crosstalk

How do I make a textbox filter in a generated static HTML document (NOT SHINY or another WEB format), so that the user can drive a value into the filter, and this value can be substituted into the text?

Comment: Which framework are you currently using instead of Shiny to communicate between a web frontend and an R backend?

Comment: My idea does not involve using a web server. Here is the implementation of the filter for a table without any WEB servers: https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/using.html

I need an analog, only for changing the text, not the table.

Comment: OK. But you’re aware that with ‘crosstalk’ you can’t execute arbitrary R code, right? The interactivity happens purely inside JavaScript.

Comment: Good. Can I write a text in a JS block in which one of the words will be substituted from the filter on the same JS?)